# Weird behaviour with html float

Tags: html, css-float

I can't understand how to solve this. I'm trying to insert my search form in a page written by someone else and it overlaps.

This is the wrong version. As you can see, it has a weird behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecFWr/2/

This is the relevant bit of code

```
<div style="width: 400px; float:right">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/search.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.color.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/search.css">
        <form id="searchForm" action="/tags/search">
            <fieldset style="border:0px; padding:0px">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Cerca...">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" value="">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="owner_id" id="owner_id" value="1">
        </form>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="padding:0;">
                <span style="display:none;">
                Documento di sintesi &nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" title="TOGGLE_RESOURCE" onclick="jQuery_1_4_x('#wiki').toggle(!jQuery_1_4_x('#wiki').is(':visible'));"><img src="/img/icons/zoom.png" alt="show">Mostra/Nascondi</a>
                </span>
                </legend>
                0 documenti di sintesi presenti<br>
                <a href="/wikitool/create/Infodisc/1"><img src="/img/icons/page_add.png" style="border: 0px; margin-bottom: -3px;" class="pngfix" alt=""> Crea un documento di sintesi</a>
                <div id="wiki" style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

If i use

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
```

instead of

```
<div style="width: 400px; float:right">
```

i get this

[image: wrong floating]

what i'm doing wrong?

I can post the whole page if needed.

Comment: First of all, put all the '<link>' references in the <head></head> section. Second, yes, please put the entire page here, with relevant CSS separate. Or better yet, create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net. I created one quickly but it's difficult to grasp the entire problem without the entire page code.

Comment: Can you post your full code on jsfiddle, with images, CSS links and scripts pointing to a remote location (i.e. a server where you're hosting them)? Also try adding clear: both; to the div too (just a hunch, probably wrong though). I will try to pop back tomorrow evening to see how you've progressed.

Comment: Dunno if it was just a coincidence but my CPU usage by Firefox shot up from 1% to 25-30% as soon as I opened that link - please look into this and sort out the issue. It looked, based on Firebug, as if there were tonnes of 404 errors from images and such like.

Comment: Obviously there are a lot of 404, because images are stored locally and you can't access from jsfiddle.

Comment: What effect do you intend to achieve? Do you want to place the search area on the right side without overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to place your search area on the right side without overlapping, you can keep your div float to the right, and make the div below it float to the left, like this:

```
<div style="width: 400px; float: right;">
  ... your div
<div>
<div style="width: 100%; float:left;">
  ... div immediately below
<div>
```

Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/ecFWr/4/